# Android development

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm currently trying to get a grip on Android development and working my way through Notepad example part 2 when this warning popped up and I can't fix it.

```
[2010-03-18 21:26:47 - androidTest] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2010-03-18 21:26:47 - androidTest] ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
```

What should I do? I'm using Eclipse with the Android ADT plugins and developing for my Hero-emulator, running Android 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart Eclipse.

Upgrade the ADT plugins. That happened for me when using SDK <1.6, with SDK 2.0 I no longer see that bug.

Comment: I recreated the virtual device and that seems to have fixed the problem.